# Permission denied(publickey) when I try to move local file to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to move my local file to ubuntu server

```
scp /Users/jaeuk/Python project/MarketTimer/MarketTimer_1.1.py ubuntu@public IP:/home/ubuntu
```

at the first time when I do that I get this output:

```
The authenticity of host 'public IP (public IP)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:*****.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'public IP' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
ubuntu@public IP: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

and it keeps printing same output:

```
ubuntu@public IP: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Comment: Probably you do not have rights in `/home/ubuntu`. Try to copy in `ubuntu@public_IP:`

Comment: @Romeo Ninov copy what?

Comment: Copy your file. Exec the command like `scp /Users/jaeuk/Python project/MarketTimer/MarketTimer_1.1.py ubuntu@public_IP:`

Comment: @RomeoNinov same error occured

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the source file should be in quotes: `scp "/Users/jaeuk/Python project/MarketTimer/MarketTimer_1.1.py" ubuntu@public_IP:`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yeah I did exactly what you said and the error occurred. I omitted quotes obove

Comment: What is the result of command: `ls -ld "/Users/jaeuk/Python project/MarketTimer/MarketTimer_1.1.py"`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov same error ` ubuntu@140.238.15.29: Permission denied (publickey) `

Answer (score 0):

You should have verified that you are using a keys pair for the local user in your client that its publickey is allowed by the server for the user ubuntu in the /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys file containing the public key of your local user pair of keys.

Runing the following command in your ssh client:

ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -L'

You will get the public key file content that should be included in the /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys file in your remote server.

If you can't access to the server you can't verify the ubuntu user authorized_keys content, so you will be able to add rebooting in rescue mode and mounting the file system with chroot or add the public key via a web dashboard of your server provider.

If you have verified that your public key setting are really ok or in any case that it still not working please run:

ssh -vvv ubuntu@public_ip

and/or

scp -vvv /Users/jaeuk/Python project/MarketTimer/MarketTimer_1.1.py ubuntu@public IP:/home/ubuntu

It should show you a lot of more useful information for know what's happening. You can paste the results for get more help about your specific case